# How to Create a materialized View that should be refreshed on updating or inserting new records into the table for which the view is created?

Tags: sql, postgresql, materialized-views, postgresql-9.5

How can I create a materialized view that would automatically refresh, when the table for which the view is created is said to be updated or inserted with new records? How can I do this in postgresql 9.5?

Comment: Views don't need "refreshing" because they don't store any data. Why do you think you need that?

Comment: say i am creating a view initially with join of two tables, later i am making some changes to either of the tables, now the view has to be updated with the changes automatically, thats all i need

Comment: That's what a view does. Why do you think it won't? A view is only a stored statement, nothing more.

Comment: sorry the refreshing has to be done on a materialized view. Edited the question as well.